# Do members of Skull and Bones at Yale University wrestle naked in mud?

Tags: united-states, school, university

[Skull and Bones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skull_and_Bones) is a secret society at Yale University.

The [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/1988/11/04/nyregion/yale-society-resists-peeks-into-its-crypt.html) claimed that:

> Initiates wrestle naked in a mud pile.

Is that part of a longstanding ritual of Skull and Bones members?

Comment: Given that it is a *secret* society and initiation rites are often one of the most protected aspects of such societies, what source do you expect to be more authoritative than the New York Times?

Comment: So... it's a college frat?

Comment: Also, the NYT isn't _claiming_ that this happens. The text surrounding the paragraph reads "Interesting enough - but the apocrypha are better. ... Initiates wrestle naked in a mud pile. [Followed by other things rumored about them] ...Not a word of this may be true. " The article is about rumors and secrets about that particular society, and doesn't make any claims that those things actually occur. I don't think this qualifies as a notable claim.

Comment: Hi @iamnotmaynard, in addition to the article from the NYTimes, this claim has been in magazines, movies, etc.  It's been a pretty consistent claim...that would be interesting to verify :)

Comment: @User001 Verify how? Who is in the position to know that would be willing to share *and* still be an authoritative source? Even if you consider ex-members who are willing to share secrets, they have been known to make things up whole-cloth before.

Comment: if they do mud wrestling at all, doing it naked makes sense. Ever tried to clean seriously muddy clothes? :)

Comment: I see your point @jwenting :)  but the ritual, if true, is rather intimate and unusual ... at least to me, since I've never been into fraternities or clubs, let alone a secret society ...